# My app keeps giving UILocalNotifications even though there are none in the code

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I put some `UILocalNotifications` in my code as a way of telling me when I had crossed over certain geographic barriers I programmed into my app. However, I've since taken these notifications out. I have even typed in "UILocalNotification" into spotlight on my mac and seen that none of my project's files contain this word. Why, then, am I still getting these notifications? I've deleted the app from my phone, then reinstalled it, and I'm still getting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UILocalNotifications` are scheduled by iOS itself (the actual operation system), i.e. once your app schedules the notification, it sits in the OS and waits to fire (or to be [cancelled](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/cancelAllLocalNotifications)). This is why deleting the app doesn't help anything. The notification doesn't sit in the app, but in the system.

You can solve this issue by calling once in your `AppDelegate` (e.g. in `didFinishLaunching`):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Once you called this line, all the notifications that have ever been scheduled by your app will be cancelled.

If you're just curios how many notifications are currently scheduled, you can check that be [retrieving all the notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/scheduledLocalNotifications) using

```
NSArray *scheduledNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
```

Comment: That's great to know. This even happens if I've scheduled an infinite amount? That is, every time I cross over a geographic barrier?

Comment: actually there is a limit to notifications that one app can schedule... I think it's at 64 at max, but I'm not sure, you should look that up if it's important for your app :)

Comment: My app shouldn't give ANY local notifications. I just did it to see if my app registered when I walked across the line. However, when I write this in code:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
  NSArray *scheduledNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    NSLog(@"SN: %@", scheduledNotifications);`

I'm still seeing output from the `NSLog`--that is, registered local notifications. Does this mean my app will still create local notifications?

Comment: no, you're probablt seeing an empty array. check for the length of the array instead.

Comment: Here is part of the output:

`"<UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x17416e640>{fire date = Friday, June 5, 2015 at 11:19:30 AM Central Daylight Time, time zone = America/Chicago (CDT) offset -18000 (Daylight), repeat interval = NSCalendarUnitDay, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Monday, June 8, 2015 at 11:19:30 AM Central Daylight Time, user info = (null)}",`

Comment: well that obviously means that there is a notification scheduled that will fire at June 8, 11:19:30... did you call `cancelAllNotifications` and made sure there are no notifications scheduled afterwards?

Comment: Yes, that's what has me confused. My project does not schedule any UILocalNotifications. After canceling all notifications, there should be none created. Yet it looks like there is. Can I be sure that it's my project creating them, or are those ANY local notifications on my OS?

Comment: That's so weird. I ran the code again (the exact same code), and now they are all canceled. Thank you for helping.

Comment: hmm very strange. if you're sure that this is the case you should file a bug report at apple!

Comment: I had to cancel them twice for some reason.